# Updating row via setRecord in QSqlTableModel

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qt5, qsqltablemodel

I use Qt 5.7, C++, SQLite database. I have `QSqlTableModel` descendant class. I update rows via `setRecord()`, `submitAll()` calls (`QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit` mode). Let's set `value_1` to `field_1` in a single row. It is saved correctly in database, also corresponding `QTableView` is automatically refreshed. When I set `value_2` to `field_1` in any row once again, modification is shown in a view, but it's not saved in database.
See [qsqltablemodel.cpp source for Qt 5.7.0](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/models/qsqltablemodel.cpp?h=v5.7.0&id=6c1e352803a6efbd8b14e5296434e22165b65084)

`bool QSqlTableModelPrivate::exec(const QString &stmt, bool prepStatement,
                                 const QSqlRecord &rec, const QSqlRecord &whereValues)`

It contains the following fragment:

```
if (editQuery.lastQuery() != stmt) {
        if (!editQuery.prepare(stmt)) {
            error = editQuery.lastError();
            return false;
        }
}
```

In my case, for the 2nd and further update calls the following condition is true: `editQuery.lastQuery() == stmt`.

stmt can contain value like

`UPDATE documents SET "mark"=? WHERE "documents"."id" = ? AND "documents"."checked" = ? AND "documents"."state" = ?`

So, `bool QSQLiteResult::prepare(const QString &query)` is not called. That is why after assignment

`int paramCount = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(d->stmt);`

this condition is true: `paramCount == 0` ([see qsql_sqlite.cpp:429](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/sql/drivers/sqlite/qsql_sqlite.cpp?h=v5.7.0&id=6c1e352803a6efbd8b14e5296434e22165b65084), `d->stmt` is a pointer to `sqlite3_stmt` and it's NULL).

It leads to the final error "Parameter count mismatch". Is it a bug, what is a workaround? Please, don't advise raw SQL, I don't want to reset model very often.